# Extending model in Angular breezejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, single-page-application

Since breeze can not submit to the database without looking out for mapped entity, then there is a need to extend the model to give you freedom to create your own calculated properties. reference: http://www.johnpapa.net/new-breeze-angular-service/

I have an extended model, using John Papa SPA project pattern,

I have created a table that require submitting a computed properties along with the users input, i.e Date/Time/UsersId i think the only way to achive this is creating an extended model check this link - http://prntscr.com/77cipy

The extended model auditId is a field in the database and bindable object,

Now the problem is, if i want to call the record from the database using ngRepeat and bind the field auditid to view using {{m.auditId}} i keep getting the object from the computed property. Now, i create another property called {{m.formattedAuditId}}

```
Object.defineProperty(Medication.prototype, 'formattedAuditId', {
            get: function () {
                var fn = this.auditId;
                return fn;
            }
        });
```

The Other View Page that get auditId from the database.

```
                 <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <th>Generic Name</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="m in vm.medication">
                            <td>{{m.formattedAuditId}}</td>
                            <td><strong>{{m.genericName}}</strong></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
```

It is still inheriting from the auditId Property i created.
Please what can i do, to bind value from the database instead of the computed property that i created.

Javascript Code:

```
function registerMedication(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Medication', Medication);

        function Medication() {
            //this.isPartial = false;
        }


        /// This part is the computed property
        Object.defineProperty(Medication.prototype, 'auditId', {
            get: function () {
                var value = moment().format('llll');
                return value;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                return value;
            }
        });

        /// This part is where i want the the value to come from the database
        Object.defineProperty(Medication.prototype, 'formattedAuditId', {
            get: function () {
                var fn = this.auditId;
                return fn;
            }
        });

    }
```

The HTML Part

```
                  <form class="contact_form" role="form" id="contact_form">

                        <fieldset class="left">

                            <label>Audit Id</label>
                            <div class="block">
                                <input data-ng-model="vm.medication.auditId"
                                       placeholder="Patient ID" class="text_input"
                                       type="text" />
                            </div>

                            <label>Generic Name</label>
                            <div class="block">
                                <input data-ng-model="vm.medication.genericName"
                                       placeholder="Generic Name" class="text_input"
                                       type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Thanks.